# too long time to obtain user location?

Tags: android, gps

I'm beginner in android development .
The problem is the code take several minutes to obtain user location so how i can fix this problem?
please help me

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
               "Location changed : Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + 
             " Lng: " + location .getLongitude(), 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
      };


        lm.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            0, 
            0, 
            locationListener);
```

Comment: show us your code! Are you talking about Emulator or real device.

Comment: you can find code above? I use real device

Comment: Have a look at this SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an/3145655#3145655)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS is always slow to start and doesn't work inside. You might want to read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html):

> I'm a big fan of location-based apps, but not their
>   seemingly-inevitable startup latency.
>
> Whether it's finding a place to eat or searching for the nearest Boris
>   Bike, I find the delay while waiting for the GPS to get a fix, and
>   then for the results list to populate, to be interminable. Once I’m in
>   a venue and ready to get some tips, check-in, or review the food, I’m
>   frequently thwarted by a lack of data connection.

Comment: Do you mean that it is normal to take many time to obtain location

Comment: Maybe. Depends on where you are when you test it. Are you inside a building?